# User message not showing in product view page

Tags: magento

In one of the Magento store, I have to restrict customers to add a product more the one time.
I checked with the cart and pass an error to the customer. But Magento does not show any message in product view page.

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice('You have already added this product in your cart');
```

Check the above code, I placed it in controller file. I thought it was correct. Let me know what I missed.

Comment: What is your code looks like? Where did you put that code (getsingleton core/session -> addnotice)?

Comment: After your code did not executed any controllers' code which will show your messages before product page? Like as: call request -> execute my code -> execute a controller -> show messages ->  redirect -> user see no messages.

Comment: @ivantedja: It is in controller file.

Comment: @diNord: No, I redirect to the product view page after set the message.

Answer (score 3):

I'll add an explanation later, try this:

`Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->addNotice('You have already added this product in your cart');`